# Finding the index of a list in a loop

Tags: python, loops

I have a simple question. If I have a for loop in python as follows:

```
for name in nameList:
```

How do I know what the index is for the element name? I know I can some something like:

```
i = 0
for name in nameList:
    i= i + 1
    if name == "something":
        nameList[i] = "something else"
```

I just feel there should be a more readable way of doing this...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the built in function [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
for index, name in enumerate(nameList):
    ...
```