# How to use the list index in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the index of a list in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549959/finding-the-index-of-a-list-in-a-loop)

Assume you have a list, where not just the values have meaning, the index has, too.

```
counts = [3,4,5,3,1]
```

Let's say that means "we have 3 objects of type zero, 4 objects of type 1 and so on".

You want to create a list of objects from that and give these objects both information details:

```
[CountObject(amount=a,type=???) for a in counts]
```

How would you do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
[CountObject(amount=a, type=i) for i, a in enumerate(counts)]
```

where `i` is then the index.

Comment: As an aside for anyone who may need this in the future: if there are several lists (say `counts` and `averages` for instance), and you also need the index, use `zip` and `itertools.count` to avoid nested tuple unpacking: `for i, c, a in zip(count(), counts, averages)`.

Comment: @lazyr: That deserves a new question post with self-answer!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
[CountObject(amount=counts[a],type=a) for a in range(len(counts))]
```

would do what you want i guess .

Comment: Yeah, but it's one of the things that is discouraged in Python.

Answer (score 1):

beside `enumerate()` you can also try `range()`, use `xrange()` if you're on python 2.x:

```
[CountObject(amount=counts[i],type=i) for i in range(len(counts))]
```